Book about a teenage half fae girl
She doesn't know she is half fae. She lives in a small town with her grandmother who is a paramedic. Her boyfriend ends up being a werewolf and dies at the end of book 1.
This book is the first in a series. I don't know when it was published, my daughter read it around 2016.
There is a big snow storm and the bad fae come to find/kidnap/kill her.
There is something about a fae kiss.

Could this be Need (2008) by Carrie Jones?

Zara White suspects there's a freaky guy semi-stalking her. She's also
obsessed with phobias. And it's true, she hasn't exactly been herself
since her stepfather died. But exiling her to shivery Maine to live
with her grandmother? That seems a bit extreme. The move is supposed
to help her stay sane...but Zara's pretty sure her mom just can't deal
with her right now.
She couldn't be more wrong. Turns out the semi-stalker is not a
figment of Zara's overactive imagination. In fact, he's still
following her, leaving behind an eerie trail of gold dust. There's
something not right - not human - in this sleepy Maine town, and all
signs point to Zara.

Wikipedia mentions that granny is a paramedic.

Betty is the family member who Zara lives with upon her arrival in
Maine. She possesses an unusual array of talents for her age, and
supports those who oppose the pixies. She is also a "were" who can
turn into a tiger. She is the town paramedic, so is constantly being
called away in a medical state of emergency. She is a terrible cook.
She usually wears plaid flannel shirts, despite being a grandmother.
Despite these various quirks, she is also a strong grandmother to
Zara.


There's also a great big snowstorm about halfway through the novel that lasts all the way to the end,

"Devyn points at me. “No more interrupting and no more attempting to hide your fear behind pathetic attempts at sarcasm, although I do appreciate it. Anyway, the kiss gives the pixie king some of the power over the woman’s soul. And it changes her into a pixie.”" I think this might be what you're referring to in regards the "fae kiss".

Those comments would be better as part of the answer.
